# Remove last character if it's a backslash with pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

How do I remove the last character of a string if it's a backslash `\` with pyspark?

I found this answer with python but I don't know how to apply it to pyspark:

```
my_string = my_string.rstrip('\\')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`trim`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#trim) function:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame([("test\\",)], ["value"])

df.withColumn("value2", F.expr(r"trim(TRAILING '\\' FROM value)")).show()

#+-----+------+
#|value|value2|
#+-----+------+
#|test\|  test|
#+-----+------+
```

Or using `regexp_replace` function:

```
df.withColumn("value2", F.regexp_replace("value", r"\\+$", "")).show()
```